# handling zeros in pandas DataFrames column divisions in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

What's the best way to handle zero denominators when dividing pandas DataFrame columns by each other in Python? for example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 0, 1, 5], "b": [0, 10, 20, 30, 50]})
df.a / df.b  # yields error
```

I'd like the ratios where the denominator is zero to be registered as NA (`numpy.nan`). How can this be done efficiently in pandas?

Casting to `float64` does not work at level of columns:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
   a   b
0  1   0
1  2  10
2  0  20
3  1  30
4  5  50

In [30]: df["a"].astype("float64") / df["b"].astype("float64")
...

FloatingPointError: divide by zero encountered in divide
```

How can I do it just for particular columns and not entire df?

Comment: If you just use floats, you'll get +/-`inf`

Comment: @askewchan: it does not work for me - see edit

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to work in floats, otherwise you will have integer division, prob not what you want

```
In [12]: df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 0, 1, 5], 
                                "b": [0, 10, 20, 30, 50]}).astype('float64')

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   a   b
0  1   0
1  2  10
2  0  20
3  1  30
4  5  50

In [14]: df.dtypes
Out[14]: 
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Here's one way

```
In [15]: x = df.a/df.b

In [16]: x
Out[16]: 
0         inf
1    0.200000
2    0.000000
3    0.033333
4    0.100000
dtype: float64

In [17]: x[np.isinf(x)] = np.nan

In [18]: x
Out[18]: 
0         NaN
1    0.200000
2    0.000000
3    0.033333
4    0.100000
dtype: float64
```

Here's another way

```
In [20]: df.a/df.b.replace({ 0 : np.nan })
Out[20]: 
0         NaN
1    0.200000
2    0.000000
3    0.033333
4    0.100000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can I cast just a column of the df into float64 and not the whole dataframe? See my edit.  I still get the error with float64 dtype

Comment: yes in 0.11; 0.10.1 or earlier *should* work, what version are u using?

Comment: also are you doing a ``np.seterr()`` anywhere in your codebase?

Comment: To clarify, couldn't one handle this now with [`pd.DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html)?

Comment: No, that just broadcasts. The issue here is how to handle ``0/0`` (and turn it into a ``nan``, as by default it will be ``inf``)

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I would like to add the following way of division that uses [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) like:

```
df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.apply(div('a', 'b'), axis=1)
```

In full:

```
In [1]:
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0], "b": [0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 0]}).astype('float64')

def div(numerator, denominator):
  return lambda row: 0.0 if row[denominator] == 0 else float(row[numerator]/row[denominator])

df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.apply(div('a', 'b'), axis=1)

Out[1]:
      a     b         c
0   1.0   0.0  0.000000
1   2.0  10.0  0.200000
2   0.0  20.0  0.000000
3   1.0  30.0  0.033333
4   5.0  50.0  0.100000
5   0.0   0.0  0.000000
```

---

This solution is slower than the one proposed by [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244367/550155):

```
df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.apply(div('a', 'b'), axis=1)
# 1.27 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df.loc[:, 'c'] = df.a/df.b.replace({ 0 : np.inf })
# 651 µs ± 44.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally when dividing by zero in Panda the value is set to infinite (`np.inf`). To avoid infinite values, use [`divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), e.g.

```
df['one'].div(df['two']).replace(np.inf, 0)
```

See:

- [Handling division by zero in Pandas calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45540015/55075)
- [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17477979/55075)

Answer (score 1):

To spell out the different behavior of pandas for columns of different dtypes, note that pandas supports division by zero for columns with numeric dtype (such as float and int64) by returning a result of inf, but for columns of object type, it raises a ZeroDivisionError exception.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953731/18135454) to a related question for examples.