# Dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I drop `nan`, `inf`, and `-inf` values from a `DataFrame` without resetting `mode.use_inf_as_null`?

Can I tell `dropna` to include `inf` in its definition of missing values so that the following works?

```
df.dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")
```

Answer (score 694, accepted):

First [`replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) infs with NaN:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

and then drop NaNs via [`dropna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all", inplace=True)
```

---

For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, np.inf, -np.inf], "col2": [2, 3, np.nan]})
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   1.0   2.0
1   inf   3.0
2  -inf   NaN

>>> df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   1.0   2.0
1   NaN   3.0
2   NaN   NaN

>>> df.dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all", inplace=True)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0   1.0   2.0
1   NaN   3.0
```

---

*The same method also works for `Series`.*

Comment: How can one "exchange" the `inf` values to a predefined `int` such as `0`, in a certain column?

Comment: @3kstc use `.replace(..., 0)`. To just do on columns you update those columns i.e. `df[cols] = df[cols].replace(..., 0)`

Comment: Maybe it's worth to specify that `replace` does not work in-place, so a new `DataFrame` is returned

Answer (score 90):

With option context, this is possible without permanently setting `use_inf_as_na`. For example:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
    df = df.dropna(subset=['col1', 'col2'], how='all')
```

Of course it can be set to treat `inf` as `NaN` permanently with

```
pd.set_option('use_inf_as_na', True)
```

---

For older versions, replace `use_inf_as_na` with `use_inf_as_null`.

Comment: This is the most readable answer and is consequently the best, even though it violates in letter (but not in spirit) the original question.

Comment: Pandas as of (at least) 0.24: `use_inf_as_null` had been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use `use_inf_as_na` instead. Add to/update answer?

Comment: This one is a better choice to treat `inf` as nulls at the global setting levels instead of operational level. This could potentially saves time imputing the values first.

Answer (score 32):

Use (fast and simple):

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]
```

This answer is based on [DougR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669790/7128154) in an other question.
Here an example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,np.nan,4,np.inf,5,-np.inf,6])
print('Input:\n',df,sep='')
df = df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]
print('\nDropped:\n',df,sep='')
```

**Result:**

```
Input:
    0
0  1.0000
1  2.0000
2  3.0000
3     NaN
4  4.0000
5     inf
6  5.0000
7    -inf
8  6.0000

Dropped:
     0
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
4  4.0
6  5.0
8  6.0
```

Comment: I  am getting this error - TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: not with my code, I guess!? Probably you try to process a column the unsupported types like strings

Answer (score 18):

Here is another method using `.loc` to replace inf with nan on a Series:

```
s.loc[(~np.isfinite(s)) & s.notnull()] = np.nan
```

So, in response to the original question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

for i in range(3): 
    df.iat[i, i] = np.inf

df
          A         B         C
0       inf  1.000000  1.000000
1  1.000000       inf  1.000000
2  1.000000  1.000000       inf

df.sum()
A    inf
B    inf
C    inf
dtype: float64

df.apply(lambda s: s[np.isfinite(s)].dropna()).sum()
A    2
B    2
C    2
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 9):

The above solution will modify the `inf`s that are not in the target columns. To remedy that,

```
lst = [np.inf, -np.inf]
to_replace = {v: lst for v in ['col1', 'col2']}
df.replace(to_replace, np.nan)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yet another solution would be to use the `isin` method. Use it to determine whether each value is infinite or missing and then chain the `all` method to determine if all the values in the rows are infinite or missing.

Finally, use the negation of that result to select the rows that don't have all infinite or missing values via boolean indexing.

```
all_inf_or_nan = df.isin([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan]).all(axis='columns')
df[~all_inf_or_nan]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`np.isinf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isinf.html). You should ensure first your dataframe series are all of type `float`. Then use `dropna` with your existing logic.

```
print(df)

       col1      col2
0 -0.441406       inf
1 -0.321105      -inf
2 -0.412857  2.223047
3 -0.356610  2.513048

df = df.mask(np.isinf)

print(df)

       col1      col2
0 -0.441406       NaN
1 -0.321105       NaN
2 -0.412857  2.223047
3 -0.356610  2.513048
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove both `Nan`, and `inf` using a single command use

```
df = df[ np.isfinite( df ).all( axis = 1) ]
```

If for some reason the above doesn't work for you, please try the following 2 steps:

```
df = df[ ~( df.isnull().any( axis = 1 ) ) ] #to remove nan
df = df[ ~( df.isin( [np.inf, -np.inf]).any(axis =1) )] #to remove inf
```

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other answers here, this one line code worked for me.

```
import numpy as np
df= df[df['required_column_name']!= np.inf]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this one and I found a one line without replace or numpy:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, np.inf],
     [1, -np.inf],
     [1, 2]],
    columns=['a', 'b']
)
df.query("b not in [inf, -inf]")
>>> a  b
 2  1  2.0
```

For some version of `pandas`, one might need to use back `` ` `` around the name of the column `b`.