# Keep finite entries only in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, I can use `df.dropna()` to drop any `NaN` entries. Is there anything similar in Pandas to drop non-finite (e.g. `Inf`) entries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
   df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: this causes my dataframe to go from 130 rows to 0. The na/inf issue I'm investigating is a column of all blanks, i believe

Comment: You can specify the axis you wish to drop NaNs over as a parameter to dropna

Comment: This will be deprecated in pandas as of 2.1.0.

Answer (score 10):

```
df[np.isfinite(df) | np.isnan(df)]
```

Comment: There's an `np.isinfinity`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.dropna()` after a `DF[DF==np.inf]=np.nan`, (unless you still want to keep the `NAN`s and only drop the `inf`s)

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly `df.drop(df==np.inf)` doesn't work. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I think, as the docstring goes: `.dropna(self, axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None)`, `df==np.inf` will get passed as `axis` argument, with should raise an exception.