# Row filtering so that we only keep finite entries

Tags: python, pandas

I found [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799245/1732769) to keep finite entries in my dataframe.

The formula is:

```
df[df == np.Inf] = np.NaN
df.dropna()
```

However, when I try it:

```
In: df[df == np.Inf] = np.NaN

## -- End pasted text --
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-88eed8630e79> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df == np.Inf] = np.NaN

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)

/Users/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _setitem_frame(self, key, value)

TypeError: Cannot do boolean setting on mixed-type frame
```

Are there any better recipes to filter rows so that we only keep **finite** entries in a specific column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7314) you can use `mode.use_inf_as_null`:

```
In [14]: df = DataFrame({'a': randint(3,size=10)})

In [15]: df['b'] = tm.choice([2,3,nan,inf,-inf], size=len(df))

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   a       b
0  1     inf
1  2    -inf
2  0  3.0000
3  1    -inf
4  2     NaN
5  1  3.0000
6  1     inf
7  0  2.0000
8  2    -inf
9  2     inf

In [17]: with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_null', True):
   ....:     res = df.dropna()
   ....:

In [18]: res
Out[18]:
   a  b
2  0  3
5  1  3
7  0  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.isinf()`

```
x = pandas.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, np.inf],
    [4, np.inf, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]
])
x[np.isinf(x)] = np.nan
print(x)

   0   1   2
0  1   2 NaN
1  4 NaN   5
2  6   7   8
```

so then `x.dropna()` gives me:

```
   0  1  2
2  6  7  8
```

To look at only subset of columns, use the `subset` kwarg (always takes a list):

```
x.dropna(subset=[1])
   0   1   2
0  1   2 NaN
2  6   7   8
```

You can also take DSM's advice and just index the dataframe directly:
`x[~np.isinf(x).any(axis=1)]`

Comment: You could also use `isinf` without using it to replace values, e.g. `x[~np.isinf(x).any(axis=1)]`.

Comment: Hmm @DSM I get: `TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types`

Comment: show me an example dataframe and code to reproduce that and we should be able to get use squared away. (@user815423426)