# Python pandas: how to remove nan and -inf values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
           time       X    Y  X_t0     X_tp0  X_t1     X_tp1  X_t2     X_tp2
0         0.002876    0   10     0       NaN   NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN
1         0.002986    0   10     0       NaN     0       NaN   NaN       NaN
2         0.037367    1   10     1  1.000000     0       NaN     0       NaN
3         0.037374    2   10     2  0.500000     1  1.000000     0       NaN
4         0.037389    3   10     3  0.333333     2  0.500000     1  1.000000
5         0.037393    4   10     4  0.250000     3  0.333333     2  0.500000

....
1030308   9.962213  256  268   256  0.000000   256  0.003906   255  0.003922
1030309  10.041799    0  268     0      -inf   256  0.000000   256  0.003906
1030310  10.118960    0  268     0       NaN     0      -inf   256  0.000000
```

I tried with the following

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_train = X_train.drop('X_t2', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t1', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('X_t2', axis=1)
X_test.fillna(X_test.mean(), inplace=True)
X_train.fillna(X_train.mean(), inplace=True)
y_train.fillna(y_train.mean(), inplace=True)
```

However, I am still getting this error `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').` whenever i try to fit a regression model  `fit(X_train, y_train)`

How can we remove both the `NaN` and `-inf` values at the same time?

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows with `NaN` and `-inf` or set them to default values?

Comment: I want to remove (or drop) them

Comment: Replace `-inf` with `NaN` (`df.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)`) then do the `dropna()`.

Comment: Thank you but i still am getting the same error when i try to fit a regression model `fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: @AChampion, when i do `df.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)`, it converts the `-inf` values to `NaN`. However, when we do `df.dropna(inplace=True)` - it doesn't remove ALL `NaN` values - it leaves some rows with `NaN` values out and that's why i am still getting the same error. Is it possible to force to remove ALL rows with `NaN` values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: @djk47463, it is NOT a duplicate please. I have seen that before I post my question. If you can't give a helping hand, don't abuse the power of stackoverflow please :(

Comment: @user2154227 That's not abuse of SO, you asked the exact same question, you notice it also says "Possible duplicate" meaning that has to be reviewed

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.isin` and check for rows that have any with `pd.DataFrame.any`.  Finally, use the boolean array to slice the dataframe.

```
df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)]

             time    X    Y  X_t0     X_tp0   X_t1     X_tp1   X_t2     X_tp2
4        0.037389    3   10     3  0.333333    2.0  0.500000    1.0  1.000000
5        0.037393    4   10     4  0.250000    3.0  0.333333    2.0  0.500000
1030308  9.962213  256  268   256  0.000000  256.0  0.003906  255.0  0.003922
```

Comment: Thank you but i still am getting the same error when i try to fit a regression model `fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: Do you have any values to large for dtype `float32`?

Comment: How do we check that? I have around 2 million rows and seems to be difficult to check it manually

Comment: `df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)].astype(np.float64)`?

Answer (score 37):

You can replace `inf` and `-inf` with `NaN`, and then select non-null rows.

```
df[df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).notnull().all(axis=1)]  # .astype(np.float64) ?
```

or

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
```

Check the type of your columns returns to make sure they are all as expected (e.g. np.float32/64) via `df.info()`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message. When i do `df.info()` here is the output`Data columns (total 9 columns):
time     1030291 non-null float64
X        1030291 non-null int64
Y        1030291 non-null int64
X_t0     1030291 non-null int64
X_tp0    1030291 non-null float64
X_t1     1030291 non-null float64
X_tp1    1030291 non-null float64
X_t2     1030291 non-null float64
X_tp2    1030291 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(3)
memory usage: 78.6 MB`

Comment: Some of those columns are integers.  I'm not sure if it would help, but try converting everything to floats via `.astype(np.float64)`.  Failing that, try `df.describe()` to check for max or min values that look out of line.

Comment: OK, I will Alexander. when i do `df.replace(-np.inf, np.nan)`, it converts the `-inf` values to `NaN`. However, when we do `df.dropna(inplace=True)` - it doesn't remove ALL `NaN` values - it leaves some rows with `NaN` values out and that's why i am still getting the same error. Is it possible to force to remove ALL rows with `NaN` values?

Comment: You need to specify the axis equal to `1` to drop rows, otherwise it is dropping columns: `df.dropna(axis=1)`. Also, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas/35783766#35783766

Answer (score 22):

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)

df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I think you'd need:

`df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)`

Comment: This answer is the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of dropping rows which contain any nulls and infinite numbers, it is more succinct to the reverse the logic of that and instead return the rows where all cells are finite numbers.  The numpy isfinite function does this and the '.all(1)' will only return a TRUE if **all** cells in row are finite.

```py
df = df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]
```

**Edit:** If you have some non-numerical dtypes in your dataframe, you might want to isolate the float dtype columns of interest. See example below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4), columns=list("ABCD"))
df['E'] = 'a_string'
df.at[2,'D'] = np.nan
df.at[1,'B'] = np.inf
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(np.float16)
df
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.325195  0.199801  0.175851  0.989883  a_string
1  0.040192       inf  0.296379  0.632059  a_string
2  0.348877  0.369374  0.976187       NaN  a_string

floating_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.floating]).columns
subset_df = df[floating_columns]
df = df[np.isfinite(subset_df).all(1)]
df
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.381104  0.119991  0.388697  0.235735  a_string
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The error I get is `TypeError: Object with dtype category cannot perform the numpy op isfinite`

Comment: @Antti I've edited the answer to include your use-case.  But with mixed dtypes, the top answer would probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to set the options so that inf values are calculated to nan;

```
s1 = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
s2 = pd.Series([2, 1, 0])
s1/s2
# Outputs:
# 0.0
# 1.0
# inf
# dtype: float64

pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)
s1/s2
# Outputs:
# 0.0
# 1.0
# NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Note you can also use context;

```
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):
    print(s1/s2)
# Outputs:
# 0.0
# 1.0
# NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: I tried all the mentioned solutions here. But i still have nan and inf values in my dataframe. Can anyone help? Also my values in the dataframe are exponential float values how can i convert that to small float values?

Answer (score 0):

`df.replace` only replaces the first occurrence on the value and thus the error

`df = list(filter(lambda x: x!= inf, df))` would remove all occurrences of `inf` and then the `drop` function can be used