# Issue when trying to remove rows containing nan or inf using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am getting this error from scikit-learn:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Which is a results from this check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602715/6810148). Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745085/python-pandas-how-to-remove-nan-and-inf-values?rq=1), I can use `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1)` because I want to detect any `nan` or `inf` values and then **removing the row containing any one of them**. However, I use Python 3.6 so the error says:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

How can I modify `df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1)` so that I can detect a row containing `inf` or `nan` and then **remove** it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it: use [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `axis=0` (which is default), as that is rows. It will drop any rows in which there is an `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,np.nan, np.inf, 3], 'y':[5,6,7,8,np.inf]})
>>> df

          x         y
0  1.000000  5.000000
1  2.000000  6.000000
2       NaN  7.000000
3       inf  8.000000
4  3.000000       inf

new_df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=0)

>>> new_df
     x    y
0  1.0  5.0
1  2.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 5 minutes til accepting your answer