# converting int in python

Tags: python, pandas

Data frame=`reviews`

I get the following errror when I try to convert rating column to integer

> ''Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer''

how can I fix it?

```
reviews.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
reviews.dropna() 

reviews['Rating'].astype('int')
```

Comment: It's hard for us to tell what the issue is if we don't know what the Dataframe looks like.

Comment: Determine what the non-numeric values are, and where they come from.

Determine what integer representation would be appropriate.

Code that!

Comment: @ Gokce , you should accept the answer as that helps to see it as answered  and removed from the un-answered queue , you can also upvote

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to first `replace` infs to NaN and then use `dropna` :

**Example DataFrame:**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, np.inf, -np.inf], 'col2':[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, np.inf, -np.inf]})

>>> df
       col1       col2
0  1.000000   6.000000
1  2.000000   7.000000
2  3.000000   8.000000
3  4.000000   9.000000
4  5.000000  10.000000
5       inf        inf
6      -inf       -inf
```

**Solution 1:**

Create a  `df_new` that way you will not loose the real dataframe and desired dataFrame will ne `df_new` separately..

```
>>> df_new = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all").astype(int)
>>> df_new
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
```

**Solution 2:**

using  `isin`  and  `~` :

```
>>> ff = df.isin([np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan]).all(axis='columns')
>>> df[~ff].astype(int)
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
```

OR Directly into original Dataframe, Use `pd.DataFrame.isin` and check for rows that have any with `pd.DataFrame.any`. Finally, use the boolean array to slice the dataframe.

```
>>> df = df[~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]).any(1)].astype(int)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
```

above taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745085/python-pandas-how-to-remove-nan-and-inf-values/45745154) courtesy to the @piRSquared

**Solution 3:**

You have liberty to use `dataFrame.mask` + `numpy.isinf` and the using `dronna()`:

```
>>> df = df.mask(np.isinf(df)).dropna().astype(int)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `.replace()` and `.dropna()` do not perform their actions in place, e.g. modify the existing dataframe unless you specify them to. However if you do specify to perform them in place your code would work:

```
reviews.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
reviews.dropna(inplace=True) 

reviews['Rating'].astype('int')
```

Or:

```
reviews = reviews.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
reviews = reviews.dropna() 

reviews['Rating'].astype('int')
```