# How to deal with "ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs" while running regressions in python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have a df with growth variables and often some initial values are 0, in which case it produces infinite values when the value moves from zero to non-zeros.

i.e.

```
.. some variables... var1   var2   var1_growth  var2_growth
                      0      0        NaN          NaN
                      0      1        NaN          inf
                      1      2        inf           1
                     1.5    2.2       0.5          0.1
...
```

when i run PanelOLS, i get an error message

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Is there a way to ignore these entries to continue with the regression without having to drop them and create a different dataset?

If not, what would be the best way to proceed? should I drop app rows with 'inf' values in both columns? is there an easy way to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't ignore these entries. This issue need to be handle before training the model, if not, you can not train it.

Depending on your data and application a different method is preferred to handle these `NaN` and `inf`. One example of code that is posted in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745085/python-pandas-how-to-remove-nan-and-inf-values) question:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(axis=1) # You can replace inf and -inf with NaN, and then select non-null rows.
```

In this case, we are removing all rows that have `inf` or `NaN` values.