# Removing inf/nan values from Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm aware that there are several posts about this, but none of the solutions seem to work and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My dataframe has data with inf values.

```
print [x for x in train_x['meh'] if not np.isfinite(x)]
```

returns

```
[inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf]
```

I tried

```
train_x.replace([numpy.inf, -numpy.inf], numpy.nan)
```

But this does not convert the `inf` to `nan`.

Next I tried

```
train_x[np.isinf(train_x)] = np.NaN
```

... which does convert the `inf` to `nan` but I'm not able to drop the `nan` rows even with `train_x.dropna()`

Essentially, I need to drop the `inf` and `nan` rows.

Comment: You have to specify `inplace=True` in both cases (`replace` and `dropna`).

Comment: or assign it back `train_x=train_x.replace([numpy.inf, -numpy.inf], numpy.nan)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746209/2285236

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just use boolean indexing

```
train_x[np.isfinite(train_x) & train_x.notnull()]
```

You actually don't even need the `train_x.notnull()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a DataFrame using

`df = pd.DataFrame({'val1': [1.1, 3.3, 2.2, np.inf], 'val2': [2.2, 6.6, np.inf, 4.4]})`

which results in

```
       val1      val2
0  1.100000  2.200000
1  3.300000  6.600000
2  2.200000       inf
3       inf  4.400000
```

If you have `inf` in more than one column you can change it to `NaN` by using

`df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if np.isinf(x) else x)`

And the result is

```
   val1  val2
0   1.1   2.2
1   3.3   6.6
2   2.2   NaN
3   NaN   4.4
```

If you have this issue on only one column (in this example, on column val1) you can do

`df.val1.apply(lambda x: np.nan if np.isinf(x) else x)`