# Bug: impossible to delete infinite values from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame `df`:

```
col1       col2
-0.441406  2.523047
-0.321105  1.555589 
-0.412857  2.223047
-0.356610  2.513048
```

When I check `df`, I see that there are some infinite values.

```
np.any(np.isnan(df))
np.all(np.isfinite(df))

False 
True
```

What is the difference between NaN and infinite? Also, how can I delete all infinite values to get True in `np.all(np.isfinite(X))`?

This is what I tried:

```
df = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(how="all")
```

But still the check of `infinite` gives me True.

[image]

Moreover, `.apply(lambda s: s[np.isfinite(s)].dropna()).count()` gives me the same number of rows of all columns as simply `df.shape`, which indicates the lack of infinite values. But in this case why `np.all(np.isfinite(df))` returns True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas),
did you try:

```
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")
```

---

`np.nan` is not considered as `finite`, you may replace `np.nan` by any finite `number` see that code for example:

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'))
df.loc[0] = [1,np.inf,-np.inf]
print df

print np.all(np.isfinite(df))

df_nan = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(subset=df.columns, how="all")
print df_nan

print np.all(np.isfinite(df_nan))

df_0 = df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0).dropna(subset=df.columns, how="all")
print df_0

print np.all(np.isfinite(df_0))
```

Result:

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  inf -inf
False
     A   B   C
0  1.0 NaN NaN
False
     A    B    C
0  1.0  0.0  0.0
True
```

Comment: How is it different from what I posted in my question? This is exactly what I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Not exactly the same because : `.dropna(subset=["col1", "col2"], how="all")` != `.dropna()`

Comment: Should I mention all the columns? Can I do `.dropna(subset=df.columns, how="all")`?

Comment: I added the screenshot of my Jupyter Notebook to my post.

Comment: Yes you can do : subset=df.columns