# loop drop columns over number of missing values

Tags: python, for-loop, missing-data

I am trying to create a loop to create a loop that helps me drop any columns with a certain amount of missing values. Can someone help me?

```
for col in df:

"""Delete columns with over 200 missing values"""

if df[col].isnull().sum() > 200:
    pd.DataFrame.drop(col)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in df:
    if df[col].isnull().sum() > 200:
        df=df.drop(col)
```

Don't drop from `pd.DataFrame`, but instead drop from `df`, and also have too assign it back.

Or even better:

```
df=df.dropna(thresh=len(df)-200,axis=1)
```

Comment: @FMmach Remember to accept if it work :-), happy to help, 

Comment: Nice :) +1 for using the `thresh` argument

Comment: @jpp Thank you :-), i like `thresh` argument too.