# Python Sklearn MinMaxScaler ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I Have a numpy array of shape: `(5380, 1071)`

I am trying to scale it's values using:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train =  scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
```

But, i get this error:

> ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I checked the maximum value using `print(X_train.argmax())` and the output is just "1027"

This array do not contain any nan or infinity value.

This is not a duplicate of

> [sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

Both errors are different.

Comment: I'd say run this `pd.isnull(X_train).sum() > 0` just to make sure no columns are showing some "hidden" nan or inf

Comment: @chitown88 False for all columns

Comment: What output of print(X_train.max()) ?

Comment: Note that `argmax` gives the INDEX of the maximum value, not the maximum value itself. Try `X_train.max()` to find the maximum value

Comment: ok, next I'd check to see what the data types are for all columns. `print (X_train.dtypes)`

Comment: aahh, the output of `X_train.max()` is `inf`. Feeling so embarrassed. is it also possible to find the column and row id of the `inf` value?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My max is 20434.95 using `df[cols].max().max()`.

Comment: Max didn't show the infinite values, but a check with `np.isinf(df[cols]).any()` finally revealed the culprits. I'm using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas) to find and replace them.