# sklearn's yeo-johnson PowerTransformer throws "ValueError: Input contains infinity" when data has no large/inf/nan values

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Yeo-Johnson method in PowerTransformer in sklearn (0.21.3; python 3.6) throws an error

```
ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

even when data is perfectly valid. Am I overlooking something? Or is this is a bug?

Code to reproduce:

```py
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print(f"sklearn version = {sklearn.__version__}")

data = np.array([1000]*100 + [980]).reshape(-1, 1)
print(f"Data stats:\n{pd.DataFrame(data).describe()}")

## Powertransform. It will give an error: "Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')"
pt = PowerTransformer(method="yeo-johnson")
pt.fit(data)
```

Output I get:

```
sklearn version = 0.21.3
Data stats:
                 0
count   101.000000
mean    999.801980
std       1.990074
min     980.000000
25%    1000.000000
50%    1000.000000
75%    1000.000000
max    1000.000000
/home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:2828: RuntimeWarning:

overflow encountered in power

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e81214808bec> in <module>()
      8 ## Powertransform. It will give ""
      9 pt = PowerTransformer(method="yeo-johnson")
---> 10 pt.fit(data)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit(self, X, y)
   2672         self : object
   2673         """
-> 2674         self._fit(X, y=y, force_transform=False)
   2675         return self
   2676 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in _fit(self, X, y, force_transform)
   2703                 X = self._scaler.fit_transform(X)
   2704             else:
-> 2705                 self._scaler.fit(X)
   2706 
   2707         return X

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in fit(self, X, y)
    637         # Reset internal state before fitting
    638         self._reset()
--> 639         return self.partial_fit(X, y)
    640 
    641     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y)
    661         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=('csr', 'csc'), copy=self.copy,
    662                         estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
--> 663                         force_all_finite='allow-nan')
    664 
    665         # Even in the case of `with_mean=False`, we update the mean anyway

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    540         if force_all_finite:
    541             _assert_all_finite(array,
--> 542                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    543 
    544     if ensure_min_samples > 0:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
     54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
     57     # for object dtype data, we only check for NaNs (GH-13254)
     58     elif X.dtype == np.dtype('object') and not allow_nan:

ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

I have seen other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968813/python-sklearn-minmaxscaler-valueerror-input-contains-infinity-or-a-value-too-l) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for) which has `inf` values. In this case, there is no value greater than 1000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug but because of the internals of `PowerTransformer`. Have a look at these lines of your error stack trace:

```py
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in _fit(self, X, y, force_transform)
   2703                 X = self._scaler.fit_transform(X)
   2704             else:
-> 2705                 self._scaler.fit(X)
   2706 
   2707         return X
```

The `standardize` parameter of `PowerTransformer` is by default set to true. In this case, the provided data will already be transformed during the call of `fit` and then the transformed data will be scaled by a `StandardScaler` (see in the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460dbf19e5e196b8ef48f9712b72a3b3c3/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L3065)).

The problem now is that your transformed data will turn out to be an array of `inf` values. You can confirm this by obtaining the lambda of the Yeo-Johnson transformation of your data with the corresponding `yeojohnson` method of `scipy` and check the transformation:

```py
from scipy.stats import yeojohnson
import numpy as np


data = np.array([1000]*100 + [980])

_, lmbda = yeojohnson(data)
print(lmbda)  # 291.47777013

data_t = (np.power(data + 1, lmbda) - 1) / lmbda
```

`data_t` is the result of the Yeo-Johnson transformation and only contains `inf` values. This is now passed to the `Standardscaler` and complains that its "input" indeed contains `inf` values. So it is not complaining about your original data, but the transformed one.

You can avoid this behavior by setting `standardize=False` and it will work fine:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
import numpy as np


data = np.array([1000]*100 + [980]).reshape(-1, 1)

pt = PowerTransformer(method="yeo-johnson", standardize=False)
data_t = pt.fit_transform(data)
```

However, along with a `RunTimeWarning`, you will still get an array full of `inf` values which might not be useful at all. But this is not because of some bug but the actual result of the transformation.

Comment: @VinayKolar does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @afsharov . That explains why. The `lambda` seems too high for this data. Setting `standardize=False` is of no use, like you mentioned.

Comment: I think, one solution could be that you apply `MinMaxScaler()` before applying power transformation. MinMaxScaler does not change data distribution but makes sure that it is between 0 and 1. This will likely reduce the changes of getting very large (infinity) values as a result of power operation in PowerTransformer.