# Skip plotting NaN and inf values in python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to skip plotting NaN and Inf values in python?

Say I have something like:

```
m1  m2  m3
4   5   2
3   2   3
4   3   4
2   5   0
4   3   8
3   4   0
2   3   4
```

and I want to plot `m1` vs `m2/m3` so there are cases I am dividing by zero, so when I go to plot it throws a `ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf`

What is the solution? Thank you.

(I am using dataframes in pandas where I go `m4 = df['m2'] / df['m3']` and go to plot `m1` vs `m4`)

Please note: there are no inf or Nan Values in the dataframe itself, but they occur after manipulation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: It's not, as that removes it from the data frame itself. This is plotting after manipulation

Answer (score 1):

According to what tools provides us *Pandas*, the easiest solution is to:

- replace *Inf* values (both positive and negative) with *NaN*,
- drop *NaN* values.

They your *Series* will contain neither *Inf*s nor *NaN*s.

So, generating `m4`, expand your instruction to:

```
m4 = (df['m2'] / df['m3']).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()
```

getting (in your case):

```
0    2.500000
1    0.666667
2    0.750000
4    0.375000
6    0.750000
dtype: float64
```

(no values for key *3* and *5*), which can be plotted as you wish.

## Edit

I noticed that (at least in *Pandas* v. *0.25*) a DataFrame scatter plot
can be generated even with *Inf* or *NaN* values in *y* column.

I did the following experiment:

1. Created *m4* **without** removing *Inf* / *Nan* values, but setting its
   name (will be needed in a moment in *join*):

   ```
   m4 = df.m2.divide(df.m3).rename('m4')
   ```
2. Replaced the second occurrence of *Inf* with *NaN*:

   ```
   m4.iat[5] = np.nan
   ```

   so now it contains both *Inf* and *NaN*.
3. Generated the plot:

   ```
   df.join(m4).plot.scatter(x='m1', y='m4');
   ```

In effect, I got the picture, without any errors.

Apparently, any *Inf* / *NaN* values are in this case silently dropped
and only **after that** the picture is generated.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to yield the rows where all its elements are finite.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np 
m1 = [4 ,3 ,4 ,2 ,4 ,3 ,2]
m2 = [5 ,2 ,3 ,5 ,3 ,4 ,3]
m3 = [2, 3, 4, 0, 8, 0, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame({'m1':m1,'m2':m2,'m3':m3})
```

Say `m4 = m2/m3`: 
 `df['m4']= df.m2/df.m3`

...and MAY CONTAIN infinite elements. To solve this problem, use `NumPy`’s `isfinite` on your data frame `df` and then use .all(1), which returns TRUE if all cells in a row are finite: 
 
 `df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]` 


For visualization purposes, please see the attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]

After this, you can now plot `m1` vs. `m4` without worrying about the infinite values:
[image]

Hope this helps!