# Remove infinite values from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to remove elements from one array `B` that have the same index as the `inf` elements from another array `A`. 
I have two numpy array such as

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4, float('inf')])
B = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

If I do `B[A>2]`, the output is `array([7, 8, 9])`. However, if I do `B[math.isfinite(A)]`, then I get an error

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I select the elements from `B` where the value in `A` is not infinity?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas) answer your question?

Comment: I am using numpy arrays, not pandas dataframes. The methods aren't quite the same

Comment: Also, I the question isn't about dropping `inf`s from `A`, but rather about dropping elements in `B` that are in the same position as `inf`s from `A`.

Comment: `math.Isfinite()` doesn't work with array as an arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the answer in your question:

`B = B[A!= float('inf')]`