# Python - Pyproj Transform Returns inf for Blank Cell in CSV. How to ignore blank cell?

Tags: python, csv, pyproj

My Python code converts latitude and longitude using pyproj. It reads this from an existing CSV file and writes a new CSV file with new code.

When it comes across a blank cell within the existing CSV file it writes in the cell of the new CSV file 'inf'

How can I stop it writing anything and leave the cell blank?

Current Python Code

```
from pyproj import Transformer
import pandas

pdf = pandas.read_csv("existing_file.csv", encoding='ANSI')
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:99999", "epsg:8888", always_xy=True)
xx, yy = transformer.transform(pdf["longitude"].values, pdf["latitude"].values)
pdf = pdf.assign(longitude=xx, latitude=yy)
pdf.to_csv("new_file.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here: [dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

I think the solution is to replace the `inf` values with nan:

```py
pdf = pdf.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you snowman2. That worked wonders. Just a note for future users that "import numpy as np" must be added for np to be readable.