# Calculate mean of dataframe with missing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that has some cells with missing data that has inf instead. e.g:

```
a       b       c
2       3       4
2       3       inf
```

I want this result:

```
2        3       4
```

Is there a way to use the mean function or find the averages of the entire data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do it with `mask` `inf` to `nan`

```
df.mask(np.isinf(df)).mean()
Out[63]: 
a    2.0
b    3.0
c    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without NumPy:

```
df.replace(float("inf"), float("nan")).mean(axis = 0)
```

You can also replace `-inf` and any other value:

```
df.replace([float("inf"), float("-inf")], float("nan")).mean(axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.nanmean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

`np.nanmean(df,axis=0)`

[You can also replace inf with NaN using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)