# How to avoid infinity when doing calculations python csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, mean, infinity

So I am working on a code where I take values from the csv file and multiply them with some numbers. Some of the values in the data are infinity so when I am calculating the mean of that column it is giving me the answer in infinity which make sense. Is there a way I can avoid calculating the that cell that has infinity in it??

I tried using this but it didn't work. Can someone tell me if I am doing this correctly?

`cop_average = df["COP"].replace('inf', np.nan).mean(skipna=True)`

After running this I am still getting "inf" in the some cells!!

Comment: Seems like you would want to do the replace first, then check the df to see what happened.  Did they replace?  Or is your replace failing?

Comment: I think my replace function is working because when I do this `cop_average = df["COP"].replace(0, np.nan).mean(skipna=True)` it works it just doesn't work on infinity for some reason plus I don't even get no error

Comment: Check it anyway.  You might learn something new :)

Comment: just filter it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55228059/14237276 before mean df there would be your df["COP"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing a string `'inf'`, you should replace the floating point representation of infinity.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = {"COP": [1, 2, np.Inf], "col2": [3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["COP"].replace(np.Inf, np.nan).mean(skipna=True)
```

Comment: Did you try my code? It is working with python=3.8.10, pandas=1.3.3, numpy=1.21.2.
If not, I need more information about your data.