# How to find the average speed?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, data-analysis

I want to calculate the average speed for each ID, i used this code

```
df_Speed=df2.groupby('ID').agg(Total_Speed=('speed Km/h', 'sum'),Total_steps=('ID', 'count')).reset_index()
df_Speed['Avg_Speed']=df_Speed['Total_Speed']/df_Speed['Total_steps']

df_Speed.head()
```

but i get *inf* as a speed !

```
ID       Total_Speed          Total_schritte    Avg_Speed
1817603  2199.422386          149               14.761224
1817615  inf                  1178              inf
1817679  inf                  452               inf
1817888  5436.540730          271               20.061036
```

how can i get the speed instead of this *inf*

Comment: How did you get the `Total_speed` column? It is very logic that inf/something=inf.

Comment: i have speed for each step for each ID and as u can see in the code i use sum to calculate the Total_Speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the data, which has somehow created infinity. As you would know, infinity divided by some constant is still infinity.

To fix this problem, you might want to tweak your data, or fill the infinities with average.

```
import numpy as np
# Replace inf with nan
df['Total_Speed'].replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
# Replace nan with mean
df['Total_Speed'].fillna(df['Total_Speed'].mean())
```

Source: [Dropping infinite values from dataframes in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17477979/dropping-infinite-values-from-dataframes-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you , that's helpfull, even if i think we will not get the real value but that solve what i want .. :D