# Linear line with matplotlib - line graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Power BI has Python visual where I can use Python code to create the visual. I am using the matplotlib and trying to create the visuals in power bi. It works fine but it is not connecting the lines as needed. Here is the code.

```py
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(R_Length, ScatterPlot, ClusterLine, TargetLine)

dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

ax = plt.gca()

dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='R_Length', y='ScatterPlot', color='blue',ax=ax)

dataset.plot(kind='line', x='R_Length', y='ClusterLine', color='black', linestyle='solid', fillstyle='full' ,ax=ax)

dataset.plot(kind='line', x='R_Length', y='TargetLine', color='red', linestyle='-' ,ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The visual it created looks like this (below). Black and Red line is not connected.
[image]

Its should look like this. Black and Red lines are connected.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

This is how data looks like
[image]

Comment: Does your `'ClusterLine'`, `'R_Length'` or `'TargetLine'` data contain NaNs or infs? If they do, then these will show as gaps in the line plot.

Comment: If that is the case, you could try using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) or you dataset, to just get rid of NaN values, or [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) to interpolate over them with some method.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of having infs in the dataset. For example, if I create some data and add a load of infs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 500)
y = 2 * x + 10

# set some y data to inf
y[50:100] = np.inf

dataset = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dataset.plot(kind="line", x="x", y="y", color="black", linestyle="solid", ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

this produces:

[image]

which has a gap where the infs were.

Instead, I can replace inf with NaNs (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17478495/1862861)) and then drop any rows containing NaN values using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

```
dataset = dataset.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
dataset = dataset.dropna()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dataset.plot(kind="line", x="x", y="y", color="black", linestyle="solid", ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

which produces:

[image]

without the gaps.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the response. I am not sure if I understood. May be me showing you the data will help. I am new to Python, so I have no luck when I tried what you sent. I have added image of how data looks like in my post

Comment: @user1403789 I think in your case, when you do `drop_duplicates` its only dropping columns that are complete duplicates, whereas from you example segment of data, I think you want to drop all duplicates of the `R_Length` column. So, instead do `dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates(subset="R_Length", keep="first")`. This should mean all those ``NULL` get dropped and the plot should hopefully work.