# Why returning Zero Division Error instead of inf in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, divide-by-zero

getting a float division by zero error when I'm expecting inf where the divisor is 0

`df['percent'] = df['value1'] / df['value2']`

Here is the df:

[image]

`ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`

It's absolutely acceptable for the `df['percent']` to read infinity, but instead I have this error so the code doesn't run.

Comment: What pandas version is this?  The DataFrame copied from the answer returns the output provided in the answer, **without** the inefficient `apply` and simply using `df.value1 / df.value2`.

Comment: @S3DEV yeah that was my bad - i should have checked that pandas supports division by 0 before posting an answer. i'll change my answer to reflect this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handling zeros in pandas DataFrames column divisions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244180/handling-zeros-in-pandas-dataframes-column-divisions-in-python)

Comment: @DerekO - For clarity the box I tested on has pandas 0.25.1 installed.  So quite old really.

Comment: Yeah, that's about two years out of date. did upgrading pandas resolve the issue?

Comment: upgraded pandas and it did not solve the issue, I will try the solution below as well

Comment: hmm that's a bit surprising. what does `pd.__version__` return?

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: pandas behaves differently for columns of different dtypes. It supports division by zero for columns with numeric dtype (such as float and int64) by returning a result of inf, but for columns of object type, it raises a ZeroDivisionError exception.

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953731/18135454) to a related question for examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest version of pandas, you should be able to divide by 0. I can run your code without getting a division by zero error.

If for some reason you are using a version of pandas that doesn't support division by 0, and cannot upgrade pandas for this particular problem, you can get around this error by using [numpy.inf](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf) whenever `df['value2']` = 0, and calculating the percentage normally otherwise:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[4,5,2,0.1],'value2':[8,7,0,0]})
df["percent"] = df.apply(lambda x: x['value1']/x['value2'] if x['value2'] != 0 else np.inf, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   value1  value2   percent
0     4.0       8  0.500000
1     5.0       7  0.714286
2     2.0       0       inf
3     0.1       0       inf
```